Docker: share the source code of react app from the host to project directory inside the container give me an error sh: 1: react-scripts: not found
I am following a tutorial to dockerize a simple React application. When I run the container of the React application without the volume option it works correctly without any problem. But when I try to map the app directory of the host to the app directory inside the container because I want to reflect the changes from the host directory to the app directory inside the container while development using the following command:
docker run -p 5005:3000 -v $(pwd):/app --name react-app21 react-application:1 I get this error 
>> sh: 1: react-scripts: not found

I am sure that I am in the right directory in the host.
note: I am using Linux WSL
Here are my docker file instructions:-
FROM node:18
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && npm start

and here is a photo fort he error
I verified that node_modules exist in the app directory of the container because when I run this command docker run -p 5005:3000  react-application:1
without volume option it works correctly
and then I ran this command: docker exec -it react-application:1 sh ls -a
and I found the node modules exist, then I tried to add volume option and create mapping using this option: docker run -p 5005:3000 -v $(pwd):/app --name react-app21 react-application:1 I got that error

What does "the right directory" have to do with it? On UNIXlike operating systems, . is not part of the PATH, so what directory you're in doesn't change which commands can or cannot be found.

What I would worry about much more here is where you have npm install configured to install things, and whether that location is found inside the PATH variable that's active inside the container.

Because I am using this short $(pwd) when I run the running command that will get the absolute path of the current directory, so I am saying that I am sure $(pwd) outputs the correct path of the project directory in the host

In reply to your second comment, I am not sure, I am just a beginner, the dependencies are installed while building the image, and the application works correctly when I start the container, but the issue is when I make the mapping or binding from the host directory to app directory inside the container

I got a better error message that says node_modules is messing!  Failed at the react-app@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2024-05-03T23_32_35_422Z-debug.log

The docker run -v option you have hides absolutely everything in your image, including its node_modules directory.  I'd recommend deleting that option.  If you want a local development environment, just installing Node is probably no more difficult than trying to use Docker here.

Thank you David, but the idea is not about development, it is about learning, I am following a tutorial, and the instructor did everything smoothly without any issues like this, so I am trying to understand why

I downloaded node modules in the host directory and put them in the .dockerignore file and it works fine

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
